# Managed property of type NSNumber? not initialized to nil

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, option-type

My Swift 3 app uses CoreData. Since the transition to Swift3/Xcode 8, I have abandoned automatic code generation for `NSManagedObject` subclasses (The new behavior, I still haven't quite figured it out yet), so I just specify non/manual and create my own classes. So far so good.

I am storing all my scalar attributes in `NSNumber?` properties, not optional scalar types like `Int?`, `Double?`, etc. (I'm not sure if optional scalar properties work well with Core Data...?).

The problem is, I can not detect the "Value not Yet Set" state of the attributes in my freshly created objects.

For example, I have:

```
class MyClass: NSManagedObject {

    // Stores a double
    @NSManaged var length: NSNumber?
}
```

Whenever I try to access the value, **I never get `nil`, but `0.0` instead:**

```
if let value = myObject.length?.doubleValue {
    // Always gets executes and value 0.0 is unwrapped
    // for new objects
} else {
    // Never gets executed
}
```

However, if I manually set it to nil on instance insertion, i.e.:

```
override awakeFromInsert(){

    super.awakeFromInsert()

    // Explicitly set to nil:
    self.length = nil
}
```

...then, I get the expected behavior.

**Did I miss something?**

I'm guessing that the `@NSManaged` attribute makes it in many ways different than a run-of-the-mill swift optional property... But I can not find mention of this behavior anywhere.

Comment: is the property nullable?

Comment: Did you define a *default value* for the property in the Core Data model inspector?

Comment: Oh, yeah. Even though I am manually generating the code using NSNumber, the checkbox for "Use Scalar Type" is checked, and the default value is set to zero! :0

Comment: Silly me. I guess that's it. I _do_ have the "Optional" box checked too, though...

Comment: This is Swift: *default value zero! :0* != `nil`(no value).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with Arun that you need to select a type (in fact, you should be getting an error if you don't).

As to your issue, by default CoreData adds defaults for numeric fields.  You can, however direct it to not set a default value by using the Data Model inspector, as shown below:

[image: Data Model Inspector in Xcode]

If you do turn off the default and leave the field empty when you create a new record, be sure the Optional checkbox is checked as well (it's a few rows above the default checkbox).

Also, if you add required fields without defaults after your first deployment, you will need to handle migration yourself as light migrations rely on the default when adding new mandatory fields to existing databases.

Comment: I *am* selecting a type (Integer16, Double, etc.). I'm just using NSNumber in my class definitions. Not sure about the alternatives; I'm open to ideas (unboxing NSNumber everywhere gets cumbersome)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot select NSNumber as datatype while selecting from the core-data .xcmodel class. When you create attribute you define a default value. Below is the screenshot which mentions the default value type . 
So if you want the value in the length as double select double as default value.

Create managed class from the Xcode. Xcode->Editor->Create NSManagedObject SubClass. You generate the classes automatically.

[image]